# How to route to static page with out change url path in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Basically,I'm trying to route to a static page like this:

`http://127.0.0.1/mypage`

=route to=>

A static page in my website folder maybe `http://127.0.0.1/static/mypage.html`

I have tried:

Add a route role:

`routes.MapRoute("StaticPage", "{pagename}", new { controller = "Common", action = "StaticPage" });`

Add an action in `Common Controller`:

```
 public ActionResult StaticPage(string pagename)
 {
     return Redirect("/static/" + pagename + ".html");
 }
```

But it will change the url and cause twice request, is there any other way(no iframe in view) to remain the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the file to the response and then return an `EmptyResult`.

```
public ActionResult StaticPage(string pagename)
{
    Response.WriteFile(Url.Content(string.Format("/static/{0}.html", pagename)));
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: But all the resources in the page will become invalid because the path now actually is view's path.

Comment: Well do you want it to be `http://www.example.com/mypage` or `http://www.example.com/static/mypage.html`? If the latter, go with your original solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply have your controller return the contents of the desired file like so:

```
public ActionResult StaticPage(String pageName) {
    return Content(GetFileContents("/static/" + pageName + ".html"));
}
public static string GetFileContents(string FileName)
{
   StreamReader sr = null;
   string FileContents = null;

   try
   {
      FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open,
                                     FileAccess.Read);
      sr = new StreamReader(fs);
      FileContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
   }
   finally
   {
      if(sr != null)
      sr.Close();
   }

    return FileContents;
}
```

Comment: But all the resources in the page will become invalid because the path now actually is view's path.